# Problem with print out to text file

Tags: .net, file, text-files

I am completely stumped. I have a program that pulls information stored in a database, assigns the database values to a corresponding class. The class has a print method that prints the values of it's fields. The users type in either an order id or order date range and then it finds those orders and prints them out to a text file. The problem I am having is that once in a awhile, depending on what id's and date's you pick, the text file will print out garbage like this. "〢Ⱒⰱ潋瑲刬瑵慨湮圬扥†′慍歲瑥㔬㈶‸⁗㈱琰⁨瑓敲瑥Ⱜ汁楳Ɒ䱉㘬㠰㌰" 
I am completely clueless here because when I debug it, all the values show correctly in the class, the print method, and result set. What could be the problem? Has anyone had this happen to them?

The OS is Windows Vista, the language I'm using is C#. I am using a StreamWriter class with a FileStream as a parameter.

This only happens with some orders. Like if I pick order 7 or order 1-6 it works fine, but if I pick 1-7, I get the weird language. ????

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure it's a kind of Da Vinci code. I let Google translate it from Chinese: "Chan Kai Zhao tinkling of gems full of water submerged masonry Orlando † 'a bland-year-old Wen㔬in financial ‸ ⁗ ㈱ Yan Lian ⁨ out Ⱜ Wen Mei juice" ;-)

Comment: Seriously. About the text file: is the text file created by your program? Is it used by other programs? Is there a big text file which is reused. Maybe somebody opens the file "manually" with an editor and saves using a wrong charset?

Comment: It's a text file created by my program that no other program uses. I save the values of the database query into my class and then print on the class fields to a text file.

Comment: Maybe you could provide other details as update to your question. Which platform (OS, framework, programming language) do you use? Maybe there is someone who ran into the same problem on that specific platform.

Comment: Which text editor you use to open the file? Did you tryed with other text editors?

Comment: Wow, yes notepad++ displays the file but not notepad. What does that mean? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes there is. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment what happens is that Notepad try to guess the encoding of the file. [Look here for how it does so](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/24/95235.aspx).

You should be explicit about the encoding of the file.

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx):

> StreamWriter defaults to using an instance of UTF8Encoding unless specified otherwise. This instance of UTF8Encoding is constructed without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM), so its GetPreamble method returns an empty byte array. To create a StreamWriter using UTF-8 encoding and a BOM, consider using a constructor that specifies encoding, such as StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding).

Answer (score 2):

that ***looks*** like a bad conversion to/from Unicode, or a culture variable being set and not applied properly.